# JAVA TCP listener

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, listener

I'm trying to make a TCP listener on java. The software should act like "Hercules" or SocketTest. Problem is, it's not recieving any connections from other computers or devices. It does connect to Hercules or SocketTest but not to my program.

```
public class Server3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7165,0,InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 7165.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected!");
        System.out.println(clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress()+" connected\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));



    String inputLine ;
    boolean connected = true;
    while (connected)
    {
        try {
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client said : "+inputLine);

            if (inputLine == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Client Disconnected!");
                connected = false;
            }
        }
        catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Timed out trying to read from socket");
        }

    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}
```

I also used ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port) but no results.
Is there any configurations to do more than just port ? Is it even possible to make this?

Comment: What does call to `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` returns on the Server side ?

Comment: @piy26 Computer name and ip

Comment: On you client implementation did you try connecting with IP or Computer Name ? Do you have multiple network interfaces on Server Side ?

Comment: @piy26 It connects using IP. No, I do not have multiple network interfaces.